# Looking to understand definite article use when referring to specific places

Tags: word-usage, articles, definite-articles

I'm trying to understand why, in certain situations, we sometimes do/don't use the definite article 'the' when referring to proper nouns (in this example, bars from my undergrad).

Specifically:
"I want to go to the 90" vs. "I want to go to 1 OAK"

In this comparison, the 90 (nine-oh) is the name of a bar and 1 OAK is the name of another bar/club. They're both proper nouns and specific places. Can anyone explain why we use 'the' for 90 while we don't for 1 OAK?

Comment: Some businesses choose to include a definite article in their names. Others do not. I don't think there's any precise rule for this.

Comment: Are you specifically concerned with the use of the definite article before a numeraled name — *the 9...* vs. *the 1...*?

Comment: Did you search the "definite-articles" tag with the word "proper", "proper noun", etc.? There are many questions & answers discussing when to use definite articles before proper nouns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some stores, restaurants, and other establishments decide to put a definite article in their names. Some examples from the US: The Home Depot, The Cheesecake Factory, The North Face, The Ritz-Carlton, *et cetera.*

There isn't really a pattern to this; most
other businesses in the same categories don't have names starting with a definite article. It's just a stylistic choice made by the owners of the business in question, one that customers may or may not respect in practice.

One complication: if you're discussing a chain of stores and need to pick out one individual establishment, you need to add the definite article. For example:

> 1. I just went to Ace Hardware.
> 2. I just went to the Ace Hardware down the street.

This creates some complications when the store's name already contains a definite article; most would avoid repeating "the" twice in "the The Home Depot down the street."

Comment: Then there are odd cases like Ohio State University, which insists on calling itself *The* Ohio State University. But no one follows their lead, omitting the *The*, and they abbreviate themselves as *OSU*, not *TOSU*

Comment: The same happens with a lot of things: bands, newspapers and magazines, books... Some have articles, some don't, and others are inconsistent. People copy other similar names and guess.